# XML- Using iteration and Copy-of in XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

I am trying to copy all the coverageData groups from first termVehicleHistory to other termVehicleHistory groups. I have multiple CoverageData groups and multiple termVehicleHistory groups. Not sure how to get the desired output. I am new to xsl and some help would be highly appreciated.

**CurrentXML**

```
   <Vehicle>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>1</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2023-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2024-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>TPL</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>DCPD</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>AP</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Coll</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Comp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Spp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <TermIdentifier>1</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Current Term</TermCaption>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>2</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2022-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2023-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>2</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 1</TermCaption>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>3</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2021-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2022-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>3</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 2</TermCaption>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>4</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2020-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2021-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>4</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 3</TermCaption>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>5</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2019-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2020-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>5</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 4</TermCaption>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>6</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2018-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2019-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>6</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 5</TermCaption>
    </termVehicleHistory>
   </Vehicle>
```

XSL that I tried -
Here **Session.getElementXmlRq** gets the whole  group and places it in a xsl file. I am trying to read through the file. **ExposureHistoryPrivate.TermVehicleCountMinusOne** is the number of iterations. In my scenario it is 5. So the loop runs for 5 times. This field **TermVehicleHistoryPrivate.AddVehicleTermHistoryContextPath** provides the xpath for TermVehicleHistory.

```
<dataRequests>
      <Session.getElementXmlRq path="~VehicleTermPrivate.AddVehicleHistoryContextPath~" xsltOut="~AccountPrivate.GetDuplicateRecordTransformPath~"></Session.getElementXmlRq>
    </dataRequests>
    <xsltRequests xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
      <xsl:for-each select="~//Session.getElementXmlRs//termVehicleHistory[1]~">
        <Request.loopRq iterations="~ExposureHistoryPrivate.TermVehicleCountMinusOne~">
          <Session.setLeafRq path="~TermVehicleHistoryPrivate.AddVehicleTermHistoryContextPath~">
            <xsl:copy-of select="./coverageData"></xsl:copy-of>
          </Session.setLeafRq>
        </Request.loopRq>
      </xsl:for-each>
    </xsltRequests>
```

**Expected result** would be CoverageData groups copied in all the other TermVehicleHistory groups.

**Expected xml**

```
   <Vehicle>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>1</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2023-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2024-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>TPL</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>DCPD</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>AP</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Coll</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Comp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Spp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <TermIdentifier>1</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Current Term</TermCaption>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>2</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2022-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2023-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>2</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 1</TermCaption>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>TPL</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>DCPD</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>AP</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Coll</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Comp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Spp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>3</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2021-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2022-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>3</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 2</TermCaption>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>TPL</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>DCPD</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>AP</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Coll</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Comp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Spp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>4</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2020-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2021-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>4</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 3</TermCaption>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>TPL</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>DCPD</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>AP</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Coll</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Comp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Spp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>5</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2019-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2020-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>5</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 4</TermCaption>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>TPL</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>DCPD</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>AP</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Coll</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Comp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Spp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
    </termVehicleHistory>
    <termVehicleHistory>
      <TermFactor>1</TermFactor>
      <AvialableTermFactor />
      <CurrentIteration>6</CurrentIteration>
      <EffectiveDate>2018-03-23</EffectiveDate>
      <ExpiryDate>2019-03-23</ExpiryDate>
      <TermIdentifier>6</TermIdentifier>
      <TermCaption>Prior Term 5</TermCaption>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>TPL</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>DCPD</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>AP</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Coll</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Comp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
      <coverageData>
        <Type>Spp</Type>
        <Value>0</Value>
        <ValueHold>0</ValueHold>
      </coverageData>
    </termVehicleHistory>
   </Vehicle>
```

Comment: Your XML seems to be missing a root element (containing all the `termVehicleHistory` elements). Can you revise the example, please?

Comment: Please edit your question and add (1) a well-formed XML input example, (2) your current XSLT and (3) the expected output (as code, not as description) - see: [mcve].

Comment: Sorry, I have added the rest of the details as well.

Comment: I made some changes to your post so that the code was visible. But what is the software you are using here? It's not plain XSLT but something else which apparently has some XSLT fragments embedded in it.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly your XML needs a root element.

For your XSLT, what I'd probably do is:

- use an identity template to copy the document (or equivalently, if you're using XSLT 3, a `mode` with `on-no-match='shallow-copy'`)
- add a template that matches the second and subsequent `termVehicleHistory` elements and inserts the `coverageData` elements into them. The template should match `termVehicleHistory[position() != 1]`, and the body of the template would copy the `termVehicleHistory` element with `xsl:copy`, then within that `xsl:copy`, copy all the `coverageData` elements (`<xsl:copy-of select="//coverageData"/>`) and then call `xsl:apply-templates` to invoke the identity template that copies everything else.

Comment: Is there anyway that you can write it in a xsl formatted code and drop it in the comments please?

Answer (score 0):

The result you show can be produced by the following stylesheet:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="/Vehicle">
    <xsl:variable name="term1" select="termVehicleHistory[1]"/>
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:copy-of select="$term1"/>
        <xsl:for-each select="termVehicleHistory[position() > 1]">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="*"/>
                <xsl:copy-of select="$term1/coverageData"/>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```